# Why does altering a textarea prevent content from being loaded into it with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on creating a quote system for comments left on my website. If a user wants to reply to what someone else said, he or she may click a "quote" button that is present on a comment, which will run a script that adds the quoted comment (and some formatting) to the sole `<textarea>` on the page. The script will also take into account any prior content in the `<textarea>`, adding quoted comments after this other content.

The problem is that if I click in the `<textarea>`, give it focus, or try to resize it as I add more quoted comments, the content will not load even though my "test" alert is run; I have to refresh the page to reset this. If I avoid altering it I can click quote buttons all day, and properly add an unlimited number of comments to the `<textarea>`. I'm a novice at Javascript, so I'm not really sure what could be causing this issue.

```
function quoteComment()
{
    $(".quote").on("click", function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

        var quoteID = this.id.match(/\d+/);
        var textContent = $("#textarea").val();

        $("#textarea").load("/php/_quote.comment.php", {

            id: quoteID,
            content: textContent

        }, function(){

           //$("#textarea").focus(); <-- this... 
           //resize code <-- or this (either alone or together) will break the functionality
           alert("test");
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `load()` on a `<textarea>`. It tries to set innerHTML internally when you need to set `value` instead.

Try using `$.post` instead and set the value in callback

```
$.post("/php/_quote.comment.php", {
  id: quoteID,
  content: textContent
}, function(data) {
  $("#textarea").val(data).focus();
  alert("test");
}).fail(function(){ alert('failed for some reason, inspect in dev tools network');})
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. By the way, is there a way for me to add line breaks using `$.post`? I was previously echoing subsequent comments with `echo $content."&#013;&#010;&#013;&#010;foobar"`, but now it actually echoes the text exactly, instead of inserting breaks.

Comment: A textarea will honor `\n` line breaks which are default created when hitting "enter"